# 3 column index for search on the 1st and the 3rd columns?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

Say I have an index (col1, col2, col3), which enables indexed search on these queries:

```
WHERE col1 = xxx
WHERE col1 = xxx AND col2 = yyy
WHERE col1 = xxx AND col2 = yyy AND AND col3 = zzz
```

If I want to search by

```
WHERE col2 = yyy AND col3 = zzz
WHERE col3 = zzz
```

I would have to create these indexes:

```
(col2, col3)
(col3)
```

Right?

But do I have to create yet another index if I want to search by:

```
WHERE col1 = yyy AND col3 = zzz
```

?

I tried to search for an answer but found nothing about searching on non-consecutive columns in an index, such as [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

Does MySQL use (col1, col2, col3) for this or do I have to create (col1, col3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the
>   index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if
>   you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed
>   search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).
>
> MySQL cannot use the index to perform lookups if the **columns do not
>   form a leftmost prefix of the index**. Suppose that you have the
>   SELECT statements shown here:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1;
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1 AND col2=val2;
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2;
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2 AND col3=val3;
> ```
>
> If an index exists on (col1, col2, col3), only the first two queries
>   use the index. The third and fourth queries do involve indexed
>   columns, but (col2) and (col2, col3) are not leftmost prefixes of
>   (col1, col2, col3).

That said, I have tested some cases on a >7,000 rows table (InnoDB). Renamed columns to `col1-3` as in the example, and created only primary ID index, and multi-column index:

[image: Table content]

Indices:

[image: Index definition]

and the following explains are showing all combinations of col1, 2 and 3 are using the index:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

So feel free to use any combination of columns once an index exists, as it will be used for any column set in the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of your columns.

---

And last, another column without index, no use of index:

[image]

---

Sources:

- MySQL Documentation: [Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: I think an `explain` with a col1,col3 search is in order, with sufficient row count to even allow an index use (ie: not 10 rows)

Comment: But what about `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1 AND col3=val3;`? It will not use (col1, col2, col3)? Or partially just use the `col1` part? Or fully using both `col1` and `col3`?

Comment: you will only know by testing it, as the manual page is ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

Left-most is certainly important, but the following shows that in the case of a col1,col3 search, the index **IS** used up to a point, then a `where` takes over, as seen in the `explain` output

```
create table t1
(   id int auto_increment primary key, -- for sanity sake for tweaks
    col1 int not null,
    col2 int not null,
    col3 int not null,
    key (col1,col2,col3)
);
```

-- I just ran this in a stored proc to generate enough rows to make any index useful
-- meaning that mysql won't use indexes on small tables, reference to follow in a bit

Run this a few hundred times:

```
insert t1 (col1,col2,col3) values (rand()*1000,rand()*1000,rand()*1000);
```

Ok, now we have sufficient data. The third one below shows the index is used, up to a point (that point being `col1`), then a `where` is resumed to find `col3`

```
explain select id from t1 where col1=7 and col2=9;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ref  | col1          | col1 | 8       | const,const |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+

explain select id from t1 where col1=7 and col2=9 and col3=8;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ref  | col1          | col1 | 12      | const,const,const |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------+------+-------------+

explain select id from t1 where col1=7 and col3=8;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ref  | col1          | col1 | 4       | const |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
```

### The Takeaway

on col1,col3 searches, technically the (col1,col2,col3) composite is used through col1

Answer (score 0):

```
(col1, col2, col3)
(col2, col3)
(col3, col1)
```

will cover all combinations of 1-, 2-, or 3-column queries of the for you describe ("=" for each test, AND'd together).

The logic:

1. For a given SELECT, build an index of all the columns that are tested with '='.  The columns can be in any order.

A little bit of experimenting comes up with the 3 indexes I showed.  (Certain other variants work equally well.)

Caveat:  If you also have `OR`, ranges, `IN(...)`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, etc, my answer may be sub-optimal.